# Only use slick.js on mobile screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, carousel

I only want the slick.js plugin to be active when on a mobile screen size, let's say under 450px for example. I want this to happen on either page load or browser resize. Slick.js does work properly if I load the page or resize to the correct width but not if I resize the browser to greater than 450px. Can this be done?

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
      if($(window).width() < 450) {
        $('.round-card-slick').slick({
        });
      } else {
        $('.round-card-slick').unslick();
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Your code makes slick run only at 450 and under. What happens are more than 450. You say it doesn't work properly. Does that mean, it still working? It should be disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is unslick keeps firing on resize even after it has been unslicked, which in turn, breaks it. A work around that my coworker came up with goes like this check..

```
var target = $('.slick-mobile-gallery');
if(target.hasClass('slick-initialized'))
  target.unslick();
```

**Update**:

The solution is built-in feature in `slick` plugin & @James Daly's answer is the true answer to this question.

Comment: @James Daly's answer is true way to do this

Answer (score 24):

btw now you can do this directly in the slick responsive settings object

```
mobileFirst: true, 
responsive: [
   {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: "unslick"
   }
]
```

Comment: Doesn't this do opposite of what they want? They only want Slick active on mobile and not on desktop. The code above triggers Slick when the window is 480px and under.

Comment: It does works when setting breakpoint extreme width like 5000, but somehow it doesn't work when having the setting as default and on responsive breakpoint 480 use the slickjs settings.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/jbvknsz4/

Comment: For the above code to work on mobile add this setting, `mobileFirst: true`

Comment: This works fine, but when the viewport goes below 480px again slick will be gone (because of unslick...)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd go about it: https://codepen.io/DriftwoodJP/pen/exxgxK

```
var init = {
  autoplay: true,
  infinite: true,
  cssEase: "linear",
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1 };


$(function () {
  var win = $(window);
  var slider = $(".slider");

  win.on("load resize", function () {
    if (win.width() < 576) {
      slider.not(".slick-initialized").slick(init);
    } else if (slider.hasClass("slick-initialized")) {
      slider.slick("unslick");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the function is not run on page load because it's only setup to be called on window resize.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $window = $(window)
    , $card = $('.round-card-slick')
    , toggleSlick;

  toggleSlick = function () {
    if ($window.width() < 450) {
      $card.slick();
    } else {
      $card.unslick();
    }
  }

  $window.resize(toggleSlick);
  toggleSlick();
});
```

To take this one step further it would be a very good idea to throttle the window.resize callbacks so that `toggleSlick` is only called every 500ms or so.

Comment: You are correct that I didn't have slick initialized on load. The problem is that unslick was firing when it was not supposed to. See my answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found for some reason that when I have the `mobileFirst: true` set it works the opposite than what I would expect. Here's what worked for me (displaying the slider only on mobile)

````
mobileFirst: true 
responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 2000,
                settings: "unslick"
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 1600,
                settings: "unslick"
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 1024,
                settings: "unslick"
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 600,
                settings: "unslick"
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).resize(function(){
  if($(window).width() < 450) {
    $('.round-card-slick').slick({
    });
  } else {
    $('.round-card-slick').slick('unslick');
  }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in the options to `unslick` the slider then on resize (with a timeout to stop it firing loads) slick it again if it's not already initialised`

```
const options = {
    mobileFirst: true, 
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 450,
            settings: "unslick"
        }
    ]
};

var slicky = $('some-slick-widget');
slicky.slick(options);

$(window).resize(function () {

    setTimeout(function () {
           
        if($(window).width() < 450 && ! slicky.hasClass("slick-initialized")) {
            slicky.slick(options);
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Match Media

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches) {
  /* the viewport is less than 768 pixels wide */
  $('.slider').slick();
}
```